# getOutputStream() has already been called for this response on second servlet request

Tags: java, spring, grails, servlets, groovy

hello i have a problem that I cannot put my finger on.....

```
servletResp.setHeader("Expires","0")
servletResp.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
servletResp.setHeader("Pragma","public")
servletResp.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=invoice.pdf")

servletResp.setContentType("application/pdf")
servletResp.setContentLength( outStream.size())
servletResponseStream.write(outStream.toByteArray())
outStream.close()
servletResponseStream.flush()
servletResponseStream.close()
```

In the above code assume that outStream has a read in pdf file.  The code renders fine on first request.  On second request I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

it doesn't matter what outputstream is.  Even if I make a brand new byte[2] and write that the same result happens.  On first request the server responds fine.  On second the above exception happens....

Any help would be welcome

Comment: The outStream.close has already closed your stream response, please provide a line number and more code

Comment: @r0ast3d No, `outStream` looks like a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, no connection to the servlet output stream.

Comment: In which line does the exception occur? What webserver are you using? Please provide more information on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question doesn't call `getOutputStream()`, or do anything that would cause it to be called.  So I'd conclude that the cause of the exception is somewhere else.

The bottom line is that you can only call `ServletResponse.getOutputStream()` and/or `getWriter()` once for a given response. Somewhere, your application is calling `getOutputStream` or `getWriter` more than once.