# Grails getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: grails, extjs

i have this method in my controller. Whick basically renders pdf file.

```
    def getUserInvoiceImage (GetInvoiceDataCommand form) {
        byte[] pdf = invoiceImageService.getUserInvoiceImage(form.invoiceId)
        response.setContentType('application/pdf')
        response.outputStream << pdf;
        response.outputStream.close()
        return false;
    }
```

When i double click it, it works okay. But when i collapse and expand my panel the following exception occurs.

```
    Software caused connection abort: socket write error. Stacktrace follows:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:64)
    at net.bull.javamelody.CounterResponseStream.write(CounterResponseStream.java:75)
    at com.tieto.msi.InvoiceImageController.getUserInvoiceImage(InvoiceImageController.groovy:13)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-08-19 12:43:15,636 ERROR KULDARIM org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver: IllegalStateException occurred when processing request: [GET] /MySupplierInvoices/invoiceImage/getUserInvoiceImage - parameters:
invoiceId: 5274216
getOutputStream() has already been called for this response. Stacktrace follows:
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:121)
    at C__Dev_MyApps_MySupplierInvoices_grails_app_views_error500_gsp.run(error500.gsp:1)
    ... 10 more
2013-08-19 12:43:15,639 WARN   grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.simple.MemoryPageFragmentCachingFilter: Throwable thrown during doFilter on request with URI: /MySupplierInvoices/grails/invoiceImage/getUserInvoiceImage.dispatch and Query: invoiceId=5274216 : Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:121)
    at C__Dev_MyApps_MySupplierInvoices_grails_app_views_error500_gsp.run(error500.gsp:1)
    ... 10 more
2013-08-19 12:43:15,640 ERROR  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/MySupplierInvoices].[grails]: Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:121)
    at C__Dev_MyApps_MySupplierInvoices_grails_app_views_error500_gsp.run(error500.gsp:1)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-08-19 12:43:15,642 ERROR  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/MySupplierInvoices].[default]: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/MySupplierInvoices] threw exception [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at net.bull.javamelody.FilterServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(FilterServletResponseWrapper.java:121)
    at C__Dev_MyApps_MySupplierInvoices_grails_app_views_error500_gsp.run(error500.gsp:1)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:271)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:179)
    at jcifs.http.NtlmHttpFilter.doFilter(NtlmHttpFilter.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

i have read a lot about this issue, but none of solutions helped me. So i`m a bit confused if i do something wrong or just this behavior which i want to reach is not possible.

Comment: seems that Grails tries to render `/views/error500.gsp` after your action

Comment: check if you have any other error in the output

Comment: i have updated the stack trace which i get

Comment: Remove the two lines `response.outputStream.close()` and `return false;`

Comment: that changes nothing, same error

Answer (score 2):

```
response.outputStream << pdf;
```

This code will automatically flush your response, so there's no need to add `close()` after. Change your code to:

```
def getUserInvoiceImage (GetInvoiceDataCommand form) {
    byte[] pdf = invoiceImageService.getUserInvoiceImage(form.invoiceId)
    response.setContentType('application/pdf')
    response.outputStream << pdf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your panel is using ajax request to get the pdf, When the panel collapse and expand ajax request happening again.

[Also see this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129873/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response-on-second-servlet-re)

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but the same error still occurs with your code

Comment: why it is bad for double ajax requests? If i double click button, then also double ajax requests are popped out.

Comment: i didn't say double ajax requests is bad, i mentioned why getUserInvoiceImage action is called again.. problem is in your server side not on the client

Answer (score 0):

- It means that your **file is not found**
- You call `flush` that's why that message does not thrown.
- Comment instruction includes `flush` calling to see the error message.
- if so , management your file existence then , uncomment `flush` calling.